# Маска для input на js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо написать маску для input на js. Сложность заключается в том что в целой части максимум должно быть четыре цифры, а в дробной максимум две цифры (например: `1111.11`). Проблема возникает когда пользователь вводит не все шесть цифр, а лишь часть (например: `22.22`). Как в этом случае понять что пользователь имел ввиду именно `22.22` а не `2222.__`?

Comment: Придётся заставлять пользователся ставить либо точку, либо ноли

Comment: А вы не хотите показать ваш js и html? Вы уже задавали вопрос про маску, но видимо так и не решились использовать готовые решения, где все эти нюансы решены за вас и на много удобней, вот к примеру [плагин к jQuery](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html) может он вам приглянется

Comment: @Darth, может сделать маску типа 0000.00 и при вводе каждого числа инпут будет заполняться справа налево (т.е когда вводит первое число 0000.01, потом 0000.13, 0001.35 и т.д)

Comment: Т.е. заставлять вводить ноли, если нужно 2222.00

Comment: @Darth, мой вариант с заполнение справа налево более удобный для пользователя не?

Comment: @r.mcreal Как в этом случае понять что пользователь имел ввиду именно 22.22 а не 2222.__? (c)

Comment: @Darth, т.е когда вводит первое число 0000.01, потом 0000.13, 0001.35 и т.д. Сделать так чтобы при вводе числа в любом случае оставлять две цифры после точки, а все что не заполнено заполнить нулями

Comment: @r.mcreal Ок я немного перефразирую ваш вопрос - 
Как в этом случае понять что пользователь имел ввиду именно 2222.__ а не 22.22?